# Make a Grammar expression for STRING.STRING.STRING on PEG.js

Tags: javascript, peg

I am looking for a peg.js grammar expression for matching against:

- `"variable"` # Fails
- `"variable."` # Fails
- `""` # Fails
- `"variable.variable"` # Ok
- `"variable.variable.variable.variable.variable"` #Ok

#### input I expect

- `{PATH: "variable.variable"}`
- `{PATH: "variable.variable.variable.variable.variable"}`

#### Sample.pegjs

```
start = 
    PATH_EXP

STRING_EXP =
    chars:[0-9a-zA-Z_]+ { return chars.join(""); }

PATH_EXP =    
    path:(STRING_EXP "." STRING_EXP) { return {PATH: path.join("")}; }
```

I don't know how to make the expression repeat, but also make it optional.

Comment: I'm not familiar with peg but regex it is like this `^variable(?:\.variable)+$` just replace variable with escaped string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with to get rid of the "." characters. I'll admit that I've never used peg.js before :)

```
PATH_EXP =    
    (first:STRING_EXP rest:("." STRING_EXP)*) {
      return {
        PATH: first +  
              rest.map(function(v) {
                return v[1]; 
              }).join("")
      };
    }
```

*edit* — oh wait this is better:

```
PATH_EXP = 
    first:STRING_EXP rest:("." s:STRING_EXP { return "." + s; })+ {
      return {
        PATH: first + rest.join('')
      };
    }
```

*edit* — clearly if you want the "." characters you'd include them in the action inside that second part. Missed that part of the question.

Comment: works with `return "." + s;` on the first return and change the `*` by `+` for avoid the first rule write on the question

Comment: @rkmax uhh ... I don't understand what that comment means. I used `*` in the second part of the rule so that "foo" would parse. Do you *want* the "." characters?  If so then yes I see.

Comment: sorry @Pointy I sure do not specify, you must comply with the list of the beginning of the question

Comment: @rkmax ah OK yes I see that now. Sorry I missed it.

Comment: @rkmax if you change it to `+` then "foo" by itself will not parse - oh wait it's not supposed to.  OK I should have read the specification more carefully!